# Is it possible to force STL set to reevaluate predicate?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdset

Consider the following data structures and code.

```
struct Sentence {
    std::string words;
    int frequency;
    Sentence(std::string words, int frequency) : words(words), frequency(frequency) {}
};
struct SentencePCompare {
    bool operator() (const Sentence* lhs, const Sentence* rhs) const {
        if (lhs->frequency != rhs->frequency) {
            return lhs->frequency > rhs->frequency;
        }
        return lhs->words.compare(rhs->words) < 0;
    }
};
std::set<Sentence*, SentencePCompare> sentencesByFrequency;

int main(){
    Sentence* foo = new Sentence("foo", 1);
    Sentence* bar = new Sentence("bar", 2);
    sentencesByFrequency.insert(foo);
    sentencesByFrequency.insert(bar);
    for (Sentence* sp : sentencesByFrequency) {
        std::cout << sp->words << std::endl;
    }
    foo->frequency = 5;
    for (Sentence* sp : sentencesByFrequency) {
        std::cout << sp->words << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is the following.

```
bar
foo
bar
foo
```

As we might expect, when an object pointed to by the pointer in the set is updated, the set does not automatically re-evaluate the predicate, even though the predicate orders the pointers based on the objects they point at.

**Is there a way to force the `std::set` to re-evaluate the predicates, so that the order is correct again?**

Comment: Perhaps `std::set` isn't the right container type for your use-case? Since keys are supposed to be constant there's no need for any reordering.

Comment: If the set isn't accessed very often, or if the modifications are reasonably well-separated from reads even though they can happen again later, it might make sense to leave it unordered and represented by e.g. a `vector`, then sort it immediately before using it, each time you use it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Do you have a recommendation for another data structure?

Comment: Also, `SentencePCompare` isn't a proper order.  Return type of `compare` cast to `bool` is code smell.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, That was actually a bug I just discovered lol. I have just fixed it in the code above.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No.

There's a reason why `set` only allows `const` access to its elements. If you sneak past that by using shallow-const pointers and custom predicates and then destroy the invariant by modifying the pointee in a way that affects ordering, you'll pay the price in the form of nasal demons.

Before C++17, you need to `erase` and `insert` again, which incurs a key copy plus node deallocation and allocation. After, you can `extract` the node, modify it, and reinsert it, which is free.

Comment: @anatolyg You literally [`extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) it.

Comment: Not really free, it avoids the cost of reallocating the node, but it's still necessary to recompute where the new node should be at, which takes about logarithmic time.

Comment: Well yes, that's the baseline cost of maintaining the invariant that you need to pay whatever you do if you want a coherent data structure.